# For loop cmd getting variable

Tags: cmd

I am trying to the get the fqdn as variable in cmd line by below method , but its not providing me the FQDN

```
fOR /F "tokens=4 delims= " %d in ('net config workstation ^| findstr /c:"Full Computer Name"') do set fqdn=%f
echo %fqdn%
```

Comment: the only token you ask for will be in `%d`, not in `%f`

Comment: I dont clearly understand

Comment: you define one token (`tokens=4`), which is `%d`, but you `set fqdn=%f`. `%f` is not defined. You should use `set fqdn=%d`.

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims= " %d in ('net config workstation ^| findstr /I /c:"Full Computer Name"') do set "fqdn=%d"
echo %fqdn%
```

If this is inside a .bat or .cmd script, double the percent on the variable to `%%d`. Also note the case insensitive switch on `findstr`.

Answer (score 0):

Output of `net config` is language dependent. On a german windows, you will need `token=3`, and obviously another search string (`Vollständiger Computername`) . Here is a language independent solution:

```
@echo off
set "x="
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('net config workstation') do if not defined x set "x=%%a"
for %%a in (%x%) do set fqdn=%%a
echo %fqdn%
```

the first `for` gets the desired line (the second line, regardless of language), the second `for` takes the *last* token of that line (regardless of how many there are).

If you really want to do it directly on command line:

```
c:> set "fqdn="
c:> for /f "skip=1 delims=" %a in ('net config workstation') do @if not defined fqdn @for %b in (%a) do @set "fqdn=%b"
c:> echo %fqdn%
```